# What problems may arise when we use a tree derived this way to classify an unseen example?

Tags: machine-learning, cart

Deriving decision-trees for numeric data, there is the option of
treating all numeric values as discrete, i.e., proceeding exactly
as we do with categorical data. What problems may arise
when we use a tree derived this way to classify an unseen
example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do this? It seems like a very bad idea:

- if your variables are continuous, many values will have different 'class' so you won't have much data per class, which is a problem
- tree building algorithm won't take into the account the fact that similar values are similar, because if you convert 0,1 and 2 into categorical values, then 0 and 2 are just as distant as 0 and 1

BTW CART algorithm uses numerical values by default, so you'd have to one-hot encode your values. Apart from the fact that CART is used in the opposite situations (I mean if you want to feed categorical data to CART, you have to encode it as continuous, like for example using one-hot encoding), you'd most likely run into memory problems, because you'll get huge feature space.